# Reading integer values from binary file using Java

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles, java-io

I am trying to write values greater than 256 using `DataOupPutStream.write()` method. When i try reading the same value using `DataInputStream.read()` it will return 0. So, i used `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` and `DataInputStream.readInt()` methods to write and retrieve values greater than 256 and it is working fine.

Refer the below code snippet i would like to know the behaviour of the compiler as what it does in the `in.readInt()` inside the `while` statement.

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("T.txt");
BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(fout);

Integer output = 0;
out.writeInt(257);
out.writeInt(2);
out.writeInt(2123);
out.writeInt(223);
out.writeInt(2132);
out.close();

FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("T.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin);

while ((output = in.readInt()) > 0) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The Output when i ran this snippet is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at compress.DataIOStream.main(DataIOStream.java:34)
257
2
2123
223
2132
```

But when i ran in debug mode i get the following output :

```
2123
223
2132
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at compress.DataIOStream.main(DataIOStream.java:34)
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The readInt() method is a method like any other.  You are getting an EOFException because that's what the Javadoc for readInt() says will happen when you reach the end of the file.

---

When I run

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("T.txt"));
out.writeInt(257);
out.writeInt(2);
out.writeInt(2123);
out.writeInt(223);
out.writeInt(2132);
out.close();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("T.txt"));
try {
    while (true) 
        System.out.println(in.readInt());
} catch (EOFException ignored) {
    System.out.println("[EOF]");
}
in.close();
```

I get this in normal and debug mode.

```
257
2
2123
223
2132
[EOF]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter..EOFException is fine. But the results differ in the debug mode and in the run mode.

Comment: When you write to System.out and System.err (when exception are written) the order of the output is not consistent/always the same. Using debug is enough to change the order of the output.

Comment: yeah.. But in the Debug mode the values read is also different. Suppose if i remove the while clause in my code snippet and replace with 5 System.out.println(in.readInt());

Comment: @rozar, The while clause makes no difference. It is more likely that the debug is correct and you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for your reply and i really appreciate it. Can you find any mistakes in my code snippet above except the EOFexception handling.

Comment: @rozar, I have shown you how I would have written it. Your `buffOut` isn't used and your while loop is waiting for something which never happens, so I simplified your example. You should trap your EOFException as I have done. If the file was larger I would use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream.