# Reading integer from bin file does modulu(256) on number which are larger than 256

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read numbers from a bin file, when it gets to a number which is larger than 256, it does a modulu(256) on that number, for example:
the number which i'm trying to read is 258, the number which was read from the file is (2) => 258mod256=2
how can I read the full number ?
This is a snippet from the code:

```
InputStream ReadBinary = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Compressed.bin"));
    int BinaryWord = 0;
    while(BinaryWord != -1) {
        BinaryWord = ReadBinary.read();
        if(BinaryWord != -1)
        System.out.println(BinaryWord + ": " + Integer.toBinaryString(BinaryWord));
```

Code for writing the file:

```
        DataOutputStream binFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\George Hanna\\eclipse-workspace\\LZW\\Compressed.bin"));
    //convert codewords to binary to send them.
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        try {
            IOFile.print(Integer.toBinaryString(result.get(i))+ " ");
            binFile.writeByte(result.get(i));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    binFile.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading integer values from binary file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135668/reading-integer-values-from-binary-file-using-java)

Comment: maybe share the code which you are using to read the file, that might be a good start..

Comment: Done, i've added a snippet

Comment: Ok, now that you have code, I see a couple of mistakes. You write with `writeByte`, which only writes one byte, between 0 and 255. Also, I guess you wanted to write `fromBinaryString` instead of `toBinaryString` where you read the integer from the file.

Comment: The values I have right now in the Bin file are something like this:
"21 
32 
34 
68 
35 
7 
27 
74 
47 
61 
95 
2 
2 
99 
13 
54 
47 
93 
11 
16 
67 
84 
66 
13 
19 
81 
101 
82 
43 
20 
36 
72 
12 
63 
51 
70 
39 
42 
83 
83 
4 
6 
73 
4 
14 
37 
108 
106 
104 
109 
10 
41 
119 
114 
26 
35 
70 
22 
2 
57 
69 
37 
52 
22 
89 
3 
4 
128 
22 
94 
58 
12 
17 
26 
7 
94 
85 
19 
29 
101 
142 
101 
145 
149 
148 
108 
67 
151 
112 
20 
82 
155 
117 
158 
120 
"....

and I just want to read them.

Comment: Does it work now, with my updated response?

Comment: Now, i'm getting big big numbers, the first number i should get is "21", but instead i got 354427460 :\

Comment: Again, I think you are missing the point here, 21 is *not* the first number. The first integer is 21 32 34 68, as integers have 4 bytes. Converted to integer, this is `21*256*256*256 + 32*256*256 + 34*256 + 68 = 354427460`.

Comment: But how can i take each number by itself ?
I need to take 21 and do some stuff with it, after that i need to take 32 and do some stuff...etc ... isn't there any way to do that ?

Comment: Sure there is, and you already implemented that. But the numbers you see are **bytes** and by design between 0 and 255, therefore what you are seeing is intended behaviour. To work with larger numbers, you need to represent them as ints(4 bytes) or longs(8 bytes). The maximum value of an int is 2147483647, the maximum value of a long is 9223372036854775807

Comment: Again, I don't know how to get each number alone...

Comment: I'll update my answer to include that

Comment: Is that what you were searching for, now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a little bit of background on how integers are stored:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

To summarize it, your file consists of *bytes*. Every byte has a value between 0 and 255.

To represent an 32-bit int, you need 4 bytes.

Java has int(4 bytes) and long(8 bytes).

The easiest way to store data in a binary file is with the `DataOutputStream`, and read it with `DataInputStream`. It will handle all those conversions for you.

```java
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("intFile.bin"));
out.writeInt(123456789);
out.close();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("intFile.bin"));
System.out.println(in.readInt());
in.close();
```

To get the single bytes from the file, do this:

```java
InputStream in_bytes = new FileInputStream("intFile.bin");
int nextByte = in_bytes.read();
while(nextByte != -1) {
    System.out.println(nextByte);
    nextByte = in_bytes.read();
}
in_bytes.close();
```

To write single bytes to a file, do this:

```java
OutputStream out_bytes = new FileOutputStream("intFile.bin");
out_bytes.write(1);
out_bytes.write(2);
out_bytes.write(3);
out_bytes.write(4);
out_bytes.close();
```

But as you already realized, what you are writing here are bytes, and therefore you are limited to the range between 0 and 255.

Comment: Let me fix that

Comment: Also, for that reason it would have been good if you posted some code yourself :)

Comment: Sorry, I had problems before when i tried to post code, nothing worked for me, but i just did add :)

Comment: Ok, in this case I think the code that you use to *write* the file is more interesting. Would you mind posting that?

Comment: Oh, the File is already written from somewhere else, I didn't even look at that, I'll add it to the code...

Comment: I'm stuck with this again, i guess there is no way to take each "NUMBER" alone, I don't know.

Comment: You keep saying 'number', i'm not sure what you mean. It's a bin file, there can not be a 300 in it, a bin file only has numbers between 0 and 255. Therefore by reading it byte by byte you already get the full 'number'. If by number, you mean 'integer', then you have to read 4 bytes at a time, and that is also what I posted here. I'd love to help you, but I think you are stuck on a concept that doesn't exist...

Comment: In case you didn't realize, the bin-file part that you postet in the other comment also only had numbers between 0 and 255. It's just impossible. If you want to get higher you need to either combine multiple bytes, or store it as text.

Comment: https://file.io/QoyPkT - Bin file
https://file.io/2NMlGt - Txt file 

I don't know if they are supposed to have the same values, but the values i need to take number by number, i mean 21 32 34 68 35 7 27 .......
but in that file i have values that are more than 255.
"a Number" is like 21, 32, 34...i need to take those from the BIN file.